# Determine the values of $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$.

Tags: statistics

I have the following exercise which I'm not sure how to solve:

Suppose that the random variable $X$ is normally distributed with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$,i.e. $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. You are told that:

$$E(X^2)=10 \text{ and } P(X>4)=0.1587$$

Determine the values of $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$.

I'm am not sure how to use these facts to derive $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$. Do I have to use software or tables? Any hint is welcome

Comment: You have $\mu^2 + \sigma^2 = 10$ from the first condition, and some condition on them from the CDF formula for the normal distribution. Do you know the latter?

Comment: $P(X>4)=0.1587$ tells you how many standard deviations about the mean $4$ is, using the CDF of a normal distribution, which gives you a second equation.  So you have two simultaneous equations in two unknowns to solve.  They are non-linear, so there may be more than one solution.

Comment: If your tables for the normal CDF use four decimal places, then you may be able to spot $0.1587$.  For higher precision, my guess is that this represents a rounding of something like $0.15865525393$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that

$$P(X\leq 4)=0.8413$$

Knowing also that $E(X^2)-\mu^2=\sigma^2$ you get

$$P\left(Z \leq\frac{4-\mu}{\sqrt{10-\mu^2} } \right)=0.8413$$

Using the tables you get

$$\frac{4-\mu}{\sqrt{10-\mu^2}}=1$$

Solve it w.r.t. $\mu$  and you get your mean: $\mu=0.75$

and immediately the variance $\sigma^2=10-0.75^2=9.4375$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What tables exactly are you using?

Comment: @user: z-score. Here find table and instructions https://www.conversion-uplift.co.uk/glossary-of-conversion-marketing/z-score/?amp

Answer (score 1):

Normal distribution $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ is
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})^2} $$
$P(X>4)$ is calculated via
$$\int_4^\infty f(x) \ dx $$ and $E[X^2]$ is calculated via
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2f(x) \ dx $$

So you can obtain your answer by simply calculating these.